# Problem with copying data from an xml file to another xml file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to copy data from file2 to file1 using xsl transformation. I am able to copy the data, but my xsd validation fails on the resulting xml file. Please help me have the data copied the right way. Here is my code:
file1.xml:

```
<Org>
   <Security xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net" />
</Org>
```

file2.xml:

```
<Profile>
   <Policy>Policy1</Policy>
   <PolicyValue>Value1</PolicyValue> 
</Profile>
```

result.xml:

```
    <Org>
       <Security xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net">
         <Security>
            <Profile>
               <Policy>Policy1</Policy>
               <PolicyValue>Value1</PolicyValue> 
            </Profile>      
        </Security>
    </Security> 
  </Org>
```

Desired output:

```
    <Org>
    <Security xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net">
    <Profile description="SecurityProfile">
        <Policy description="SecurityProfile">Policy1</Policy>
        <PolicyValue description="SecurityProfile">Value1</PolicyValue> 
    </Profile>      
    </Security> 
   </Org>
```

Here is the code from my xsl file:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Org']/*[local-name()='Security']]">
  <xsl:variable name="description" select="document($lookup)/Entity/@description" />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="document($lookup)/Profile" />
                </xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>     
  </xsl:template>
```

My output file has nested Security element which is causing the validation failure. Can somebody please help me in fixing the issue. Also I need to add an attribute value recursively to all the elements that are copied. I was able to set the variable to read the attribute from lookup file. I was not able to set the attribute values to the child nodes.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider walking down the tree of first xml with templates for *Org* and *Security* and in latter template, run multiple `<xsl:for-each>` on external nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Org">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Security"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Security">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each select="document('SecurityProfile2.xml')/Profile">
             <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:attribute name="description">SecurityProfile</xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:for-each select="document('file2.xml')/Profile/*">
                  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                      <xsl:attribute name="description">SecurityProfile</xsl:attribute>
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:element>                    
               </xsl:for-each>
             </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The 'Security' is in 2 different places in the xml file which needs to be transformed with one having child elements. Above solution removes the child nodes in the second occurrence and copies the nodes from file2, how can we retain the child nodes of Security and copy the data from file2. When we copying the element from file2 with <xsl:element name="{local-name()}"> it is not getting the required attributes, how can we get them? Also, the attributes on Security element are removed. Is it possible to add some attributes to Security element. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am away from my machine at the moment but I was almost sure the result of this solution matched your posted desired output. Maybe you are running with different XML data?

Comment: I had taken the first node from the xml file for Security which has an attribute and no child node. I posted that as desired output. When I applied the code provided by you to the xml file I observed that it removed the child node from the second Security node. Sorry, for the confusion. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please check your desired output. There is only one *Security* node and I just checked my run and it rendered exactly as you desired.